# How to say "too busy for..." in german

Tags: preposition

I want to know how to say, for example " I'm too busy to practice German".
Would that be something like "ich bin zu beschäftigt zu Deutsch üben?". I would really appreciate it, sometimes I have a hard time making sense of german prepositions.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE! Since your question is about the right preposition (in German), it's interesting that you chose *too busy **for*** in the headline and *too busy **to*** in your example.

Comment: Lol, that's true! I guess I was thinking about a noun in the headline and about a verb in the example.

Answer (score 3):

You can say either

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt, **um*** Deutsch zu üben.

or

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt zu**m** Deutschüben. (*Deutschüben* = one word, nominalized)

The preposition is always *zu*. In the first alternative you don't have a mere infinitive, but an *erweiterter Infinitiv* beginning with *um* which is considered to be subclause-equivalent. In the second alternative, you have a nominalized verb (*das Deutschüben*), so it becomes a substantive preceeded by an article. Because the preposition *zu* requires the dative, the prepositional phrase originally would be *zu dem Deutschüben*. However, in this case *zu dem* always merges into *zum*.

---

*Without *um*, the sentence would read *I'm too busy (with) **learning German***.

Answer (score 2):

Although

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt, (um) Deutsch zu üben.

is possible and sort of a more literal translation, I would say that the phrase

> Ich habe zu viel zu tun, um Deutsch zu üben.

or

> Ich komme nicht dazu, Deutsch zu üben.

are more idiomatic in German.

Comment: *Ich bin zu beschäftigt Deutsch zu üben* (without *um*) would more likely mean *I'm too busy **with** learning German* from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm too busy to practice German.

---

As already explained in other answers, both

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt, um Deutsch zu üben.

and

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt zum Deutschüben.

are acceptable ways to express the aforementioned statement.

**However,** note that both ways can be somewhat confusing because they could be interpreted differently: In both cases, the general sentence structure reflects the meaning of "in order to", that is, explaining the purpose of something. Outside of the "zu ... um zu" construction, "um zu" very uniquely means "in order to" in German.

As a native German speaker, I am regularly wary of using "zu ... um zu" for fear of being misunderstood, and generally try to circumnavigate this construction, for which there are several options:

- Only to be used in writing, and even there, it sounds rather old-fashioned:

> Ich bin zu beschäftigt, als dass ich Deutsch üben könnte.

- More modern, and idiomatic both in written and spoken language:

> Ich bin so beschäftigt, dass ich nicht/kein Deutsch üben kann.

- Also acceptable in all contexts, but switches the order in which information is given around:

> Ich kann nicht/kein Deutsch üben. Dazu bin ich zu beschäftigt.

Comment: I don't get your point regarding the ambiguity. What could you mistakingly understand?

Comment: @Nearoo: "I am too busy, and the purpose of my being so busy is so I cannot practice German."

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure if this interpretation would make sense semantically, both in German and English. Whenever you're too <anything>, you're too <anything> _to_ (/for)  <something> , you can't be e.g. too small just on its own, which would be the case if you're describing the purpose with the second part of the sentence.

Comment: @Nearoo: The intention may be pretty obvious (well, to most people, at least) in the example given here, but consider this one: "The announced number of participants was too high to get the permission." Now, does this mean the permission was denied because the announced number of participants exceeded the acceptable maximum number? Or does it mean the participant count was intentionally overestimated in order to reach some minimum participant number required to get a permission? Both seem reasonable, and they will probably become clear from context, but IMHO, the fact that you need to know ...

Comment: ... the context just to tell whether a given sentence means one thing or basically the opposite thereof is a sufficient reason to avoid the construction for the sake of clarity.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to my ears. The former is clearly the case. Further, I'm pretty sure you can't express purpose for adjectives, it must be verbs. Example: "I was too tired to take a test" / "I was _being_ too tired to take a test", although it still doesn't entirely make sense, because you're still not defining _what_ you're too tired for.

Comment: @Nearoo: Good to know - then maybe it's not as ambiguous in English as I thought. I have removed the respective remark in my answer, thank you. In German, "Die angekündigte Teilnehmerzahl war zu hoch, um die Erlaubnis zu erhalten." allows for both interpretations.